# OpenGL immediate mode in window coordinates

Tags: c++, c, opengl, immediate-mode

As the title says, I'm trying to draw stuff in immediate mode in window coordinates - which is probably the wrong term. That is, the coordinate system that has its origin in the top left corner of the window, with its Y axis expanding downwards the height of the window, and its X axis expanding sidewards along the width. I want to be able to draw a line from the top-left corner to the bottom-right corner like this:

```
glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
  glVertex2f(1280.0f, 720.0f);
glEnd();
```

Yes, I am aware that immediate mode is deprecated, but please answer within old OpenGL's context.
How do I need to set up OpenGL's matrix stack so I can draw in window coordinates, like seen above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `GL_LINE` won't work with `glBegin()`, you need `GL_LINES`.  Yay type-less "enums".

Comment: In short glOrtho is your solution.

Comment: `glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION ); glLoadIdentity(); glOrtho( 0.0, 1280.0, 720.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0 ); glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW ); glLoadIdentity(); drawStuff();`

Comment: @genpfault oops, sorry didn't think this question already had an answer. Sorry about that. And yea, i always confuse things like that.

Comment: @calcyss: Eh, no worries, good luck with your future OpenGL-ing!